# A quite weird array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my problem, I'm programming a game and I need to use a very simple array, the problem is that I create it, everything's ok, and the next line, the values of an entire line in the array change and I don't understand why, here is my code :

```
var ciblesPossibles = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            ciblesPossibles[i,j] = 1 + portee(i, j, ID, pos, carte.effet.portee) + duBonCote(i, ID, carte.effet.ciblesLegales);
        }
        console.log('1/ ciblesPossibles['+i+',x] = ' + ciblesPossibles[i,0] + ciblesPossibles[i,1] + ciblesPossibles[i,2] + ciblesPossibles[i,3] + ciblesPossibles[i,4]);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log('2/ ciblesPossibles['+i+',x] = ' + ciblesPossibles[i,0] + ciblesPossibles[i,1] + ciblesPossibles[i,2] + ciblesPossibles[i,3] + ciblesPossibles[i,4]);
    }

    var max = maxTab(ciblesPossibles);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            ciblesPossibles[i,j] = Math.floor(ciblesPossibles[i,j] / max);
            console.log(ciblesPossibles[i,j]);
        }
    }
```

portee() and duBonCote() are two functions which return just 1 or 0.
When I'm at the console.log('/1...'), I have something like 33222 and 22211 (it's what I want), but when I'm at the console.log('/2...'), I have 22211 and 22211 ... What can make the first line change in my array ?

Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays are accessed as `a[i][j]`, not `a[i,j]`.

The latter will be treated as a use of the comma operator, and evaluates to just `a[j]`, i.e. a one-dimensional matrix.

You'll be wanting something more like:

```
var ciblesPossibles = [];   // create array to hold rows - NB: not "new Array():
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    ciblesPossibles[i] = [];    // create the individual row
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        ciblesPossibles[i][j] = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know understand how javascript arrays work... Thanks for your answer !